# Possible Job Listings order bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

If I search with [what = java and where = London](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=java&location=london&range=20) then the search ordering seems to be partially broken.  Specifically search relevance and proximity are entirely ignored and date ordering is used.  Several javascript and php jobs are listed above Java in terms of search relevance.  Both seem to be date ordered.

Comment: Since all these are in london, they all resolve to the same location, hence no apparent location sort (after distance jobs are sorted by date). The relevance does seem off... we'll look in to this.

Comment: @KorneelBouman has anyone looked into it? If not relevant anymore I think this report can be safely closed and even deleted.

Answer (score 1):

All sorting issues with the careers job list should have been sorted out last night.  Please let us know if you notice any more issues with this.